# error using ABNT style for biblatex along with hyperref package and compiling with make4ht

Tags: biblatex, make4ht, abnt

A document using `abnt` style for `biblatex` and also including `hyperref` packages leads to an error when compiling `make4ht`. The following error appears:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    21   Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    21   Paragraph ended before \@secondoftwo was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    21   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    21   Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    21   Missing number, treated as zero.
```

In the `.log` file lies the following message:

```
! Argument of \@secondoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.21 Test \cite{knuth1986}.

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
```

The `.tex` example to reproduce this error is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{article.bib}
@book{knuth1986,
  address = {Reading, Mass},
  series = {Computers \& typesetting},
  title = {The {TeXbook}},
  isbn = {9780201134476 9780201134483},
  number = {A},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  author = {Knuth, Donald Ervin and Knuth, Donald Ervin},
  year = {1986},
  keywords = {TeX (Computer file), Computerized typesetting, Mathematics printing, Computer programs},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=abnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{article.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Test \cite{knuth1986}.
%\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{TeX StackExchange}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Removing the option `style=abnt`, it compiles without errors.

Versions used:

```
biblatex version: 2020/12/31 3.16
hyperref version: 2020-05-15 v7.00
make4ht version: v0.3f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit strange issue, but it seems to be related to the fact that both TeX4ht and BibLaTeX patches the `\ifthenelse` command. We need to make some workarounds because of it in `biblatex.4ht`, but it seems that these fail with the `abnt` style. In the end, I've found that loading of the Nameref package helps. That's because Nameref redefines `\ifthenelse` too and this version works with both BibLaTeX and TeX4ht.

So, you can try this version of `biblatex-hooks.4ht`:

```
% biblatex-hooks.4ht (2020-10-17-13:53), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2020-10-17-13:53}

\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\blx@mknoautolang{%
    \blx@lbxinput{\blx@languagename}%
    {}{}%
  }%
  \def\blx@lbxinput@iii#1#2{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lng@#2}%
  \:IfFileExists{#1.lbx}
    {\blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#1}{language '#2' -> '#1'}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@suffmaptried@#2}
      {}
      {\blx@warning@noline{%
          File '#1.lbx' not found!\MessageBreak
          Ignoring mapping '#2' -> '#1'}%
       \global\cslet{blx@suffmaptried@#2}\@empty}%
     \blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#2}{language '#2'}}}

}

\RequirePackage{nameref}
```

This is early hooks file, which means that it is loaded at the same moment as you use `\usepackage{biblatex}`. Usual `.4ht` files are processed at the end of document preamble and it is too late for this to work.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: note that a (rather complex) document of mine that uses biblatex doesn't compile anymore after this fix. The error message is similar than the one reported here. Commenting out the loading of `nameref` in `biblatex-hooks.4ht` cures it. So maybe loading nameref unconditionally with biblatex is not such a good idea.

Comment: @JSpitzm ah, that's bad. could you please make a MWE for testing?

Comment: I try and post it to the tracker if I succeed.

Comment: Report with MWE created here: https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?534

Comment: @JSpitzm thanks, I will take a look