# Error messages when compiling with make4ht and using biblatex and geometry

Tags: biblatex, geometry, make4ht

Using `biblatex` and `geometry` leads to error when compiling with `make4ht`. The example document is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `make4ht -x` or `-l` option gives the following error message:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./testbibgeom.tex    4        
File ended while scanning use of \@for.
```

and the `.log`file has:

```
Runaway argument?
\CurrentOption: =\@classoptionslist \do {\@ifundefined {KV@Gm@\CurrentOption \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@for.
<inserted text>
\parl.4 \begin
        {document}
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

Although there are those error messages, the `.html` seems ok.

Comment: It seems to be caused by the recent change in `biblatex-hooks.4ht`, as it now requires the Nameref package to fix other issues. Strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be introduced by my [fix for another issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619816/2891). When you use BibLaTeX, TeX4ht loads the `biblatex-hooks.4ht` file:

```
\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\blx@mknoautolang{%
    \blx@lbxinput{\blx@languagename}%
    {}{}%
  }%
  \def\blx@lbxinput@iii#1#2{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lng@#2}%
  \:IfFileExists{#1.lbx}
    {\blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#1}{language '#2' -> '#1'}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@suffmaptried@#2}
      {}
      {\blx@warning@noline{%
          File '#1.lbx' not found!\MessageBreak
          Ignoring mapping '#2' -> '#1'}%
       \global\cslet{blx@suffmaptried@#2}\@empty}%
     \blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#2}{language '#2'}}}

}

\RequirePackage{nameref}
```

The important bit is

```
\RequirePackage{nameref}
```

At this moment, some catcodes are changed (most notably `:` character can be part of command names). I suspect that this leads to wrong execution of some macros in Nameref.

We still need to load Nameref before BibLaTeX, but it needs to be loaded using the usual catcodes for packages. We can achieve this thanks to the new LaTeX hook mechanism:

```
\AddToHook{package/before/biblatex}{\RequirePackage{nameref}}
```

The full `biblatex-hooks.4ht` now looks like this:

```
% biblatex-hooks.4ht (2021-10-22-14:44), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2020 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-10-22-14:44}

\:AtEndOfPackage{%
  \def\blx@mknoautolang{%
    \blx@lbxinput{\blx@languagename}%
    {}{}%
  }%
  \def\blx@lbxinput@iii#1#2{%
  \global\csundef{blx@lng@#2}%
  \:IfFileExists{#1.lbx}
    {\blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#1}{language '#2' -> '#1'}}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@suffmaptried@#2}
      {}
      {\blx@warning@noline{%
          File '#1.lbx' not found!\MessageBreak
          Ignoring mapping '#2' -> '#1'}%
       \global\cslet{blx@suffmaptried@#2}\@empty}%
     \blx@lbxinput@iv{#2}{#2}{language '#2'}}}

}
\AddToHook{package/before/biblatex}{\RequirePackage{nameref}}
```

Your sample now should compile correctly.

Comment: Michal, you got me curious here. What's the relation between `biblatex` and `nameref` that leads to this requirement? Usually, `nameref` is loaded super late by `hyperref` (it comes in an `AtBeginDocument` inside `hyperref`, which should come very late in the preamble). So, for regular compilation, I'd expect `nameref` coming after `biblatex` to be the standard.

Comment: @gusbrs it is because I need to fix this issue with BibLaTeX's patching of `\ifthenelse`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619816/2891. Maybe it would be best if BibLaTeX added test for TeX4ht, as we can put it's macro to `\ifthenelse` ourselves, I just thought it would be easier to fix it myself.

Comment: Oh, damn, and `nameref` also patches `\ifthenelse`... right. But I still sort of don't get why it has to be different from the regular compilation loading order. If `biblatex` can be loaded safely before `nameref` usually, why would it have to be otherwise for `make4ht`? Wouldn't some intervention in `nameref.4ht` do the job in a safer way? I mean, I still don't know well why `hyperref` arranges for `nameref` to be loaded that late, but I suppose there's a reason...

Comment: @gusbrs this issue is really strange. I still don't even understand what why it happens, so it starts to be quite frustrating. This kind of package clashes is really hard to debug. Even if I delete the whole contents of `nameref.4ht` or `hyperref.4ht`, the issue persists. If someone could find the source, I will gladly use a more clean solution :)

Comment: Michal, I also don't get it well. You just got me curious, because I'm also struggling with a "`nameref` coming so late" issue (other macro though), so it struck me as atypical. On the other hand, `hyperref`'s "to go" recommendation for compatibility issues is "load `nameref` before it", so it cannot be a big deal either.  :)

Comment: @gusbrs I hope that this was the last issue caused by this, but I have suspicion that it will be not :)

Comment: Well, this way of things of "each redefining another's stuff", which is the way things work for (La)TeX and the package ecosystem, is definitely "slippery". I hope this is your last round with this one too, but I also hope that the new hook management system will be enough of a tool to discipline this a little. :)