# etoolbox error with make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, etoolbox, make4ht

The following example, despite a the generated `HTML` seems okay, shows an error message.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lin_impressions_1936,
  address = {Berkeley},
  title = {Impressions on {Reaching} {America}},
  booktitle = {Land without {Ghosts}: {Chinese} {Impressions} of {America} from the {MidNineteenth} {Century} to the {Present}},
  publisher = {University of California Press},
  author = {Lin, Y. T.},
  editor = {Arkush, R. D. and Lee, L. O.},
  year = {1936},
  pages = {160--63},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum~\cite{lin_impressions_1936}.
Dolor sit amet~\textcite{lin_impressions_1936}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Compiled with:

```
make4ht -x -u article
```

Generated `HTML`:

[image]

Error message:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.aux        10       Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifrefcontextdefaults' undefined.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.aux        12       Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifrefcontextdefaults' undefined.
```

Content of `.log` file:

```
! Package etoolbox Error: Boolean '\ifrefcontextdefaults' undefined.

See the etoolbox package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.12 ...pressions_1936}{nty/global//global/global}

Your command was ignored.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is an error in `biblatex.4ht` which happens only in the XeTeX mode. This is the culprit:

```
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \def\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext#1#2#3{%
  \global\boolfalse{refcontextdefaults}%
  \csxdef{blx@assignedrefcontextbib@#1@\detokenize{#2}}{\detokenize{#3}}}
\fi
```

It redefines some internal macro when XeTeX is active, adding additional `\detokenize` to protect special characters. It seems that the `refcontextdefaults` boolean variable is not used by BibLaTeX anymore, so we can just remove this line. It seems to fix the issue.

Here is the full `biblatex.4ht` with the fix:

```
% biblatex.4ht (2021-12-27-13:23), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2007-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2021 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2021-12-27-13:23}

   \def\make:blx:ver#1.#2#3\relax{%
   %\ifdim#1pt< 3pt \xdef\blx:ver:no{2}\else\xdef\blx:ver:no{3}\fi%
   \gdef\blx:ver:no{#1}
   \gdef\blx:subver:no{#2}
}
\expandafter\make:blx:ver\abx@version.0\relax
\ifx\a:printshorthands\Undef\let\blx@shorthands\@empty\fi
\ifx\blx@startbib\:UnDef
 \pend:def\blx@shorthands{%
   \pend:def\blx@bibinit{%
       \HAssign\shorthands:cnt=0
       \NewConfigure{printfield-shorthand}{2}%
       \Configure{printfield-shorthand}%
         {\gHAdvance\shorthands:cnt by 1\relax
          \ifnum \shorthands:cnt=1 \a:printshorthands
          \else                    \c:printshorthands \fi
         }
         {\d:printshorthands}%
   \append:def\endtheshorthands{\b:printshorthands}%
   \csname a:@shorthands\endcsname}
}
\ifx\b:printshorthands\Undef\let\endtheshorthands\@empty\fi
\def\a:entryhead{CVR}
\def\a:entryhead:full{CV Radhakrishnan}
\ifx\bib@macro@entryhead:name\UnDef
  \let\bib@macro@entryhead:name\@empty\fi
\ifx\bib@macro@entryhead:full\UnDef
  \let\bib@macro@entryhead:full\@empty\fi
  \gdef\BibFileName[#1]#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname
       BibFileName#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcount\sv:sec:cnt
\def\bibSecConfigure{%
  \let\save:section\section
  \global\sv:sec:cnt=\c@secnumdepth
  \def\section{\@ifstar
      {\c@secnumdepth=0\relax\save:section}%
      {\c@secnumdepth=\sv:sec:cnt\save:section}}%
}
\gHAssign\bibN=0
\ifdefined\TE@hook\else%
\def\TE@hook{}%
\fi%

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \Configure{ifthenelse}{\TE@hook}
}
  \:CheckOption{ooffice}\if:Option
   \def\bibConfigure{\ConfigureList{thebibliography}%
      {\IgnorePar\EndP \gHAdvance\bib:N by 1
       \HCode{<text:bibliography text:name="bib-\bib:N" >
              <text:bibliography-source>\Hnewline
             <text:index-title-template>}
           \NoFonts\ref:name\EndNoFonts
       \HCode{</text:index-title-template>\Hnewline
%
           <text:bibliography-entry-template\Hnewline
            text:bibliography-type="custom1"
            text:style-name="Bibliography11">\Hnewline
%
            <text:index-entry-bibliography
             text:bibliography-data-field="identifier"/>\Hnewline
%
           <text:index-entry-span>: </text:index-entry-span>\Hnewline
           <text:index-entry-bibliography
            text:bibliography-data-field="author" />\Hnewline
           <text:index-entry-span>, </text:index-entry-span>\Hnewline
%
           <text:index-entry-bibliography
            text:bibliography-data-field="title" />\Hnewline
           <text:index-entry-span>, </text:index-entry-span>\Hnewline
%
           <text:index-entry-bibliography
            text:bibliography-data-field="year" />\Hnewline
           </text:bibliography-entry-template>\Hnewline\Hnewline
           </text:bibliography-source>\Hnewline
           <text:index-body>\Hnewline}%
         \let\en:bib=\empty
      }%
      {\en:bib\HCode{</text:index-body></text:bibliography>}}
      {\en:bib\gdef\en:bib{\HCode{</text:p>\Hnewline}}%
        \HCode{<text:p text:style-name="p-bibitem">}%
        \gHAdvance\bibN by 1
        \HCode{<text:reference-mark
          text:name="X0-\csname BIB-\bibN\endcsname">%
          </text:reference-mark>}%
      }%
      {}{}
  }

  \else
    \def\bibConfigure{%
  \ConfigureList{thebibliography}
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP \EndP
    \HCode {<dl class="thebibliography">}%
%
% This is for linking citations with biblist items which
% are in a different file when output is split into different
% chunks. [CVR 2012-09-27]
%
%
% <biblatex-2.2>
%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\BibFileName[\therefsection]{\FileName}}%
%
% </biblatex-2.2>
%
    \PushMacro \end:itm \global \let \end:itm =\empty}%
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP
    \PopMacro \end:itm \global \let \end:itm \end:itm \EndP
    \HCode {</dd></dl>}\ShowPar}%
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP \gHAdvance \bibN by 1
    \end:itm \global \def \end:itm {\EndP \Tg </dd>}%
    \HCode {<dt id="X\therefsection-\abx@field@entrykey"
      class="thebibliography">}\bgroup \bf}%
  {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi \EndP
    \egroup
    \HCode {</dt><dd\Hnewline id="bib-\bibN"
      class="thebibliography">}%
    \par \ShowPar}%
 }

 \fi
\NewConfigure{printshorthands}{4}
\NewConfigure{@shorthands}[1]{\concat:config\a:@shorthands{#1}}
\let\a:@shorthands\empty
% \def\nolinkurl{\o:url:}
% \def\blx@checksum{\ifx \blx@checksum@old \blx@checksum@new \else
%   \blx@warning@noline {Page references have changed.\MessageBreak
%     Rerun to get references right}\@tempswatrue \blx@reruntrue \fi
%   \@nameuse {blx@rerun}}
\def\blx@checksum#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@tempcnta\the\numexpr0#2*0#3\relax
  \blx@tempcntb\blx@tempcnta
  \divide\blx@tempcntb10
  \multiply\blx@tempcntb10
  \advance\blx@tempcnta-\blx@tempcntb
  \xdef#1{#1\the\blx@tempcnta}%
  \endgroup}

\@ifpackagelater{biblatex}{2018/03/01}{\let\blx:pend:def\pend:defI}{\let\blx:pend:def\pend:def}
\blx:pend:def\blx@bibliography{\bibSecConfigure%
  \pend:def\blx@bibinit{%
    \bibConfigure
     \csname onthebibliography:list\endcsname
  }%
}
\let\en:bib\@empty
\newcounter{bib}
\ifnum\blx:ver:no < 3
 \protected\def\blx@bbl@entry#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  \def\texht@bibkey{#1}
  \edef\abx@field@entrykey{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \global\advance\c@bib 1
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\expandafter\string\gdef
    \string\csname\space BIB-\thebib\string\endcsname
     {\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\texht@bibkey}}%
  \Tag{)QX\therefsection-#1}{\thebib}%
  \blx@setoptions@type{#2}%
  \blx@bbl@options{#3}%
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \edef\blx@bbl@data{blx@data@\the\c@refsection @\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \csuse\blx@bbl@data
  \cslet\blx@bbl@data\@empty
  \blx@bbl@addfield{entrykey}{\abx@field@entrykey}%
  \blx@bbl@addfield{entrytype}{#2}%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{options}
    {}
    {\blx@bbl@fieldedef{options}{\expandonce\abx@field@options}}}
%
 \protected\def\blx@finentry{%
  \unspace
  \a:finentry
      \finentrypunct
      \blx@postpunct
  \b:finentry
  \blx@initunit
 }
%
\else
% Biblatex 3.0
%
% Hacks for biblatex
% MakeUppercase is redefined by tex4ht, biblatex tries to redefine it as well, but it relies on original
% LaTeX version:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{%
  \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
  \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##1##2\reserved@a}%
  \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
  \let\UTF@two@octets@noexpand\@empty
  \let\UTF@three@octets@noexpand\@empty
  \let\UTF@four@octets@noexpand\@empty
  \blx@hook@uc\protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{#1}}%
  \reserved@a
}}
% Same applies also for \MakeLowercase
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeLowercase}[1]{{%
  \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##2##1\reserved@a}%
  \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
  \let\UTF@two@octets@noexpand\@empty
  \let\UTF@three@octets@noexpand\@empty
  \let\UTF@four@octets@noexpand\@empty
  \blx@hook@lc\protected@edef\reserved@a{\lowercase{#1}}%
  \reserved@a
}}

% I don't really understand this, but language processing is broken by default
% with biblatex. It loads language file, but it executes code which should be
% executed only in the case if the language file fails, it displays an error message
% and language handling doesn't work. When we execute following code, the language
% files are loaded before checking of the success and it seems to work.

\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
      {% This is required for languages which are never explicitly selected
        % It seems this code was executed also with Polyglossia, where it caused compilation error
        \@ifpackageloaded{polyglossia}{}{%
        \def\do#1{\blx@lbxinput{#1}{}{}}%
       \ifx\@empty\bbl@loaded\else%
       \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\bbl@loaded}%
      \fi}}{}%
}
\fi % end of version boolean
\NewConfigure{finentry}{2}
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:printfield-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{printfield-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{printfield-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:printfield-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:printfield-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@printfield:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@printfield\endcsname\:tempc
\NewConfigure{printfield}[1]{\def\a:printfield##1{#1}}
\Configure{printfield}{%
    \Configure{#1}%
       {\HCode{<!--#1-->}}%
       {\HCode{<!--/#1-->}}%
}
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:bibstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{bibstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{bibstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:bibstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:bibstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@bibstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@bibstring\endcsname\:tempc
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:bibcpstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{bibcpstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{bibcpstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:bibcpstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:bibcpstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@bibcpstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@bibcpstring\endcsname\:tempc
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:biblcstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{biblcstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{biblcstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:biblcstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:biblcstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@biblcstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@biblcstring\endcsname\:tempc
\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname a:bibucstring-#2\endcsname\relax
      \NewConfigure{bibucstring-#2}{2}%
      \a:printfield{bibucstring-#2}%
   \fi
   \Configure{blx@unit}%
       {\csname a:bibucstring-#2\endcsname}%
       {\csname b:bibucstring-#2\endcsname}%
   \csname o:\string\blx@bibucstring:\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
}
\expandafter\HLet\csname\string\blx@bibucstring\endcsname\:tempc
\NewConfigure{biblatex-style}[2]{%
   \def\:temp{#1}%
   \ifx \:temp\blx@cbxfile
      #2%
      \global\let\biblatex:style\def
   \fi
}

\def\biblatex:style{}
\Configure{biblatex-style}{}{}

\pend:def\at:docend{%
   \ifx \UnDef\biblatex:style
      \:warning{\string\Configure{biblatex-style}{\blx@cbxfile}{...}
         not available}%
   \fi
}
\let\blx:item\@item
\def\@item[#1]{%
  \blx:item[#1]%
  \ifhmode \spacefactor\blx@sf@par\fi
}
\let\blx@resetpuncthook\@empty
\let\blx@csq@ifkernmark\@empty
\newskip\blx@unitmark
\blx@unitmark=10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\let\abx@aux@page\@gobbletwo
\let\abx@aux@fnpage\@gobbletwo
\let\abx@aux@refsection\@gobbletwo
%
% <Kristian.Debrabant@cs.kuleuven.be> reported that After updating
% biblatex and biblatex.ht to versions 2.2 respectively
% 2012-09-28-17:49 (using MiKTeX 2.9 64 bit), tex4ht seemed no longer
% respected the defernumbers option in biblatex.sty: When applied to
% the attached file tex4hterror.tex.
%
% The problem was due to nullifying \abx@aux@number which in fact
% should have been redefined to \blx@aux@number when defernumbers
% option is true.
%
% This is done now and as per Kristian, the fix works fine now.
%
\ifnum\blx:ver:no < 3
%
 \protected\def\blx@aux@number#1#2#3#4{%
  \blx@bbl@addentryfield{\detokenize{#2}}{#3}{localnumber}{#4}%
  \ifblank{#4}%
    {}%
    {\csgdef{blx@labelnumber@#3}{#4}%
     %\blx@addchecksum{#1}{#4} % this can cause a nodocument error!
     }}
%
 \iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}%
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{labelnumber}%
     \let\blx@thelabelnumber\blx@addlabelnumber
     \let\abx@aux@number\blx@aux@number}%
    {\let\blx@thelabelnumber\relax
     \let\abx@aux@number\@gobblefour}
%
\else
  \def\@gobblefive#1#2#3#4#5{}%
 \protected\def\blx@aux@number#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \blx@bbl@addentryfield{\detokenize{#2}}{#3}{localnumber}{#4}{#5}%
   \blx@bbl@addentryfield{\detokenize{#2}}{#3}{labelnumber}{#4}{#5}%
   \global\toggletrue{blx@localnumber}%
   \ifblank{#5}
    {}
    {\csgdef{blx@labelnumber@#3@#4}{#5}}}

 \iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}%
    {\setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{labelnumber}%
     \let\blx@thelabelnumber\blx@addlabelnumber
     \let\abx@aux@number\blx@aux@number}%
    {\let\blx@thelabelnumber\relax
     \let\abx@aux@number\@gobblefive}
\fi % end of version boolean
%
\AtEndDocument{%
  \def\abx@aux@page#1#2{\blx@addpagesum{#1}{#2}}%
  \def\abx@aux@fnpage#1#2{\blx@addpagesum{#1}{#2}}%
}
%
\def\blx@begunit{%
  \toggletrue{blx@tempa}%
  \iftoggle{blx@insert}%
    {\iftoggle{blx@unit}%
       {\begingroup
          \let\blx@begunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endnounit\@empty
          \blx@unitpunct\blx@postpunct
        \endgroup
        \global\togglefalse{blx@unit}%
        \togglefalse{blx@tempa}}
       {\blx@postpunct}%
     \iftoggle{blx@block}%
       {\begingroup
          \let\blx@begunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endunit\@empty
          \let\blx@endnounit\@empty
          \newblockpunct
        \endgroup
        \global\togglefalse{blx@block}%
        \togglefalse{blx@tempa}}%
       {}}%
    {}%
  \blx@postpunct
  \blx@imc@resetpunctfont
  \iftoggle{blx@tempa}%
    {}%
    {\global\togglefalse{blx@insert}}%
  \csname a:blx@unit\endcsname
  \blx@leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \Configure{blx@unit}{}{}%
}
\def\blx@endunit{%
  \endgroup
  \csname b:blx@unit\endcsname%
  \Configure{blx@unit}{}{}%
  \global\toggletrue{blx@insert}%
  \global\toggletrue{blx@lastins}%
}
\NewConfigure{blx@unit}{2}

%
   \else
\fi

\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \def\abx@aux@defaultrefcontext#1#2#3{%        
  \csxdef{blx@assignedrefcontextbib@#1@\detokenize{#2}}{\detokenize{#3}}}
\fi
\renewrobustcmd*{\addnbspace}{%
  \unspace\blx@postpunct%
  % insert real non-breaking space character
  \nobreakspace\blx@imc@resetpunctfont}

   \NewConfigure{thebibliography}{4}
\append:def\blx@bibinit{\a:bibinit}%
\NewConfigure{bibinit}{1}%

   \let\blx@anchors\@empty
\let\bib@field@entrykey\@empty

\protected\def\blx@anchor{%
  \xifinlist{X\the\c@refsection -%@
    \bib@field@entrykey}{\blx@anchors}%
    {}%
    {\listxadd\blx@anchors{X\the\c@refsection -%@
      \bib@field@entrykey}%
     \hyper:natanchorstart{X\the\c@refsection -%@
      \bib@field@entrykey}%
     \hyper:natanchorend}}

\protected\def\blx@bibhyperref{%
   \@ifnextchar[%]
     {\blx@bibhyperref@i}%
     {\blx@bibhyperref@i[\bib@field@entrykey]}}%

\long\def\blx@bibhyperref@i[#1]#2{%
   \hyper:natlinkstart{X\the\c@refsection -%@
     #1}%
     #2\hyper:natlinkend}%

\protected\long\def\blx@bibhyperlink#1#2{%
   \hyper:natlinkstart{X\the\c@refsection -%:
     #1}%
     #2\hyper:natlinkend}%

\protected\long\def\blx@bibhypertarget#1#2{%
   \@bsphack
   \hyper:natanchorstart{X\the\c@refsection -%:
     #1}%
   \@esphack
     #2\hyper:natanchorend}%

\let\blx@ifhyperref\@firstoftwo

% Oleg Domanov odomanov@yandex.ru reports:
% tex4ht ends with an error when compiles biblatex files. I'm on
% Windows, texlive 2012. I put here a minimal example and files
% generated with the command latexmk test && mk4ht oolatex test
%
% https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn1zm40htqs13mf/t4htlink.zip
%
% There is a superfluous \relax in the file test.tmp, line 65 which
% seems to cause the error.
%
% Changes to cope with biblatex upgrade caused this problem. It is now
% fixed. --CVR 2012/10/26
%
\:CheckOption{ooffice}\if:Option
 \def\hyper:natanchorstart#1{\Link{}{#1}\EndLink}%
 \def\hyper:natlinkstart#1{\Link{#1}{}}%
\else
 \def\hyper:natanchorstart#1{%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname\relax%
        \Tag{)Qpage.\thepage}{\file:id}%
        \HCode{<a id="page.\thepage"></a>}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname{0}%
       \fi
      \Link[\csname BibFileName\therefsection\endcsname]{}{#1}\EndLink}
 \def\hyper:natlinkstart#1{%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname\relax%
        \Tag{)Qpage.\thepage}{\file:id}%
        \HCode{<a id="page.\thepage"></a>}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname QXpage.\thepage\endcsname{0}%
       \fi
      \Link[\csname BibFileName\therefsection\endcsname]{#1}{}}
\fi
\def\hyper:natanchorend{}
\def\hyper:natlinkend{\EndLink}
\def\writeCiteLink#1{\immediate\write\@mainaux{%
    \string\@namedef{#1.\thepage}{\FileName}}}
\let\blx@addpagesum\@gobbletwo
% \let\nolinkurl\relax

\ifx\blx:ver:no < 3
%
% biblatex 2.9a
%
% Newly added to process {keylist} environment (CVR)
%
\let\keylist\description
\let\endkeylist\enddescription
\def\keyitem#1{\item[#1]}%
%
%
\else
%
% biblatex 3.0
%
\let\keylist\Un:def
\let\endkeylist\Un:def
\newenvironment*{keylist}
  {\list{}{%
     \setlength{\labelwidth}{1.25in}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{10pt}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
     \raggedright%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss\bfseries##1}}}
  {\endlist}
%
\def\keyitem#1{%
  \item[#1]
  \begingroup
    \keyitemhook%
    \blx@bibinit%
    \midsentence\ifbibstring{#1}{}{\latintext}\biblstring{#1}%
    \expandafter\lbx@initnamehook\lsmartoftext%
    \par\nobreak
    \midsentence\ifbibstring{#1}{}{\latintext}\bibsstring{#1}%
    \expandafter\lbx@initnamehook\ssmartoftext%
  \endgroup
  \par\nobreak}
\fi  % End of version boolean

\ConfigureList{keylist}%
   {\EndP\HCode{<dl \a:LRdir class="description">}%
      \PushMacro\end:itm
\global\let\end:itm=\empty}%
   {\PopMacro\end:itm \global\let\end:itm \end:itm
\EndP\HCode{</dd></dl>}\ShowPar}%
   {\end:itm \global\def\end:itm{\EndP\Tg</dd>}\HCode{<dt
        class="description">}\bgroup \bf}%
   {\egroup\EndP\HCode{</dt><dd\Hnewline class="description">}}

   \let\:temp\do
  \def\do#1{%
    \patchcmd#1%
      {\color@begingroup}%
      {\color@begingroup\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}%
      {\togglefalse{blx@tempa}\listbreak}%
      {}}%
  \docsvlist{%
    \@footnotetext,%          latex
    \H@@footnotetext,%        hyperref
    \scr@saved@footnotetext,% koma-script 3.x
    \l@dold@footnotetext,%    ledmac
    \l@doldold@footnotetext,% ledmac
    \@fntORI}%                frenchle
\let\do\:temp

   \pend:defI\blx@backref{%
  % prevent duplicate backlink on the same page
  \ifcsdef{bk##1\thepage}{}{%
    % insert link to the page
    \html:addr\Link-{}{x\last:haddr}\EndLink%
    % save link to the .xref file
    \Tag{)Q##1\thepage}{x\last:haddr}%
    % we need to save the link destination in .xref file
    % too, otherwise \Link command would issue warning
    \Tag{)Qx\last:haddr}{\FileNumber}%
  }%
  % declare this backlink destination as used, so we don't
  % declare another one with the same name
  \expandafter\gdef\csname bk##1\thepage\endcsname{}%
}

% version of \hyperlink that links back to saved link in citation
% on the given DVI page
\def\bbx:hyperlink#1#2{
  % first argument is destination used by Hyperref, second is page number
  % test if we saved link to the current bibitem and page
  \ifTag{)Q\abx@field@entrykey#2}{%
      \Link{\LikeRef{)Q\abx@field@entrykey#2}}{}#2\EndLink%
  }%
  {#2}% print just page number if there is no saved link
  }

% we need to redefine pageref format, which is used for printing of
% back link page numbers. custom \hyperlink command is used
\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{%
  % we redefine \hyperlink command to link page numbers in backreferences
  % back to the citations on the given pages
  \let\orig:hyperlink\hyperlink%
  \let\hyperlink\bbx:hyperlink%
  \ifnumless{\abx@pagerefstyle}{0}
    {\usebibmacro{list:plain}%
     \ifhyperref
       {\hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}}
       {#1}}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:init}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{pageref:comp}{#1}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
       {\usebibmacro{pageref:dump}}
       {}}
  \let\hyperlink\orig:hyperlink%
}


\Hinput{biblatex}
\endinput
```

Comment: it did work in this example, but it when using alongside this [hook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620434/error-messages-when-compiling-with-make4ht-and-using-biblatex-and-geometry) another error appears: `File ended while scanning use of \@for.`

Comment: @LEo do you use some local patches from my previous answers? I think that that example should work with current TeX4ht sources.

Comment: This last error occur while using alongside the patch provided here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620434/error-messages-when-compiling-with-make4ht-and-using-biblatex-and-geometry   Is this patch no longer necessary?

Comment: @LEo try to compile your file without any patches for hyperref of biblatex that I provided in the past. It should be all integrated into TeX4ht sources in the up-to-date TeX Live.